# Понятие окрестностей

Tags: семантика

Окрестности города — это территория города или смежные с ней территории за городом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смежные с ней территории.

---

[ОКРЕСТНОСТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

а) Местность, прилегающая к чему-либо.

*Окрестности города, деревни, озера.*

---

б) Окружающая местность, окружающее пространство.

*Осматривать достопримечательности окрестностей города*.

*Гулять по окрестностям посёлка.*

Comment: А каким понятием объединить Москву и города Подмосковья? Округа, околоток?

Comment: Округ подходит: Административное, политическое, военное, хозяйственное подразделение государственной территории. Околоток - это про район города и устаревшее.

Comment: А могут ли слова "околица", "округа" означать также смежные территории (как и окрестности)?

Comment: В словаре Ефремовой у околицы есть значение: Окружающая местность; окрестность, округа. У округи как раз такое значение: Окружающая, прилегающая к чему-л. местность; окрестность. Но это разговорное слово.

Comment: А околоток может?

Comment: В словаре нашёл. Округа — окружающая местность, не ииеющая чётких границ малонаселённая территория, входящая в личную сферу людей, которые постоянно живут на ней, ощущают себя коллективом и считают друг друга своими, полагают расстояния внутри неё близкими. Не значит ли это, что округа скорее означает внутренние территории, чем внешние?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103746/discussion-between--and-oleedd).

Comment: У околотка в словаре Ефремовой тоже есть такое значение: Окружающая местность; окрестность, околица. || Нет, это не значит. Ключевое в начале - что местность окружающая. То есть округа относительно чего-то. Есть распространённое выражение "*съехались со всей округи*". Оно раскрывает суть.

Comment: То есть если собрались за одном столом жители соседних изб и изб, находящихся чуть поодаль, мы не имеем права их мыслить проживающими в одной округе?

Comment: *Далеко/близко* - понятие относительное, субъективное. Если автор считает избы далёкими, он их округой не назовёт. А другой может назвать, если посчитает, что они относительно близко.

Comment: Мрй вопрос изначально вот что подразумевал: какие из этих слов означают территорию за чертой района, селения, а какие внутри черты (по понятию околица — изгородь вокруг селения). Окрестности и округа, по-вашему, — это территории за чертой района, города, селения? Тогда соседние избы не могут быть причислены к ним, так как они находятся на территории, внутри черты.

Comment: Околица внутри - окраина селения; край деревни, села (из словаря). Округа относительно **чего-либо**. То есть соседние избы по отношению к данной избе - тоже округа. Но обычно это про что-то большое.

Comment: Одно из значений околицы также может включать округу? То есть допустимо "Найти в околице" — то есть найти у соседних изб?

Comment: Такое есть только в словаре Ефремовой. Словарь Кузнецова не рассматривает такое значение. Думаю, что стоит воздержаться от его использования, так как оно противоречит основному значению.

Comment: Так ведь всё-таки можно ли объединить избы понятием "окрестности", или окрестности всегда подразумевают смежные с селением (а не более мелким объектом) территории? А вот околоток по значению округи может включать избы, недалеко расположенные друг от друга?

Comment: *Околоток* - устаревшее слово. Думаю, что не стоит их изучать, так как люди их не поймут. (Я с ним не сталкивался.) *Окрестности* - про что-то большое. *Окрестности дома/улицы* - звучит странно. Стилистика нарушается.

Comment: Представьте себе два круга, один, вписанный в другой (внутренний и внешний). Внутренний круг — селение, область между внутренним и внешним кругом — соседние (ближние) селения. Заштрихованная область будет означать область, которую охватывает рассматриваемое понятие. Понятия "окрестности"(А), "округа"(Б), "околица"(В), "околоток"(Г) будут включать: 1)и внутренний круг, и область между внутр. и внеш.; 2)внутренний круг; 3)область между внутр. и внеш.; 4)в одном своём значении внутренний, в другом — область между внутренним и внешним? Установите, пожалуйста, соответствие между буквами и цифрами

Comment: 2) Округ. 3) А, Б, Г. 4) В (но лишь край внутреннего).

Comment: Предположим, нам нужно найтм мальчишку, который живёт на нашей улице и ещё одного, живущего в нашем районе города. Мы можем утверждать, что "где-то в окрестностях, околотке, округе обитает мальчишка"?

Comment: Эти слова надо к чему-то применить. Например: *окресности озера*. Нужно указать "внутренний круг".

Comment: А могут ли эти слова произноситься без указания на "внутренний круг", так, чтобы территория отсчитывалась от говорящего? Как бы вы стилистически решили этот вопрос лучше (положим, озера нет)? Неужто "где-то на районе", "в пределах района" "живёт мальчик" складнее?

Comment: В разговорном стиле (это не будет образцово) это будет подмена слов "*вокруг*", "*неподалёку*". Всё просто: *где-то в этом районе*.

Comment: А если речь идёт о розыске преступника, например? "Неподалёку" уже не тау ладно звучит.

Comment: Окрестности, околоток и округа в этом случае тоже что-то не звучат.

Comment: Маш, а, Маш, говорят, что в окрестностях появился мужчина-преступник, ты слышала что-нибудь о нём?

Comment: Не звучит. Нужно в окрестностях чего-то. Аж требуется на слух.

Comment: А если в этом предложении вписать "в нашей округе"?

Comment: Округа - это не наше, это чужое, то, что снаружи "нашего". А тут нужно "в нашем районе".

Comment: По сути округа, окрестности, околоток и в одном из значений околица — синонимы?

Comment: Да, но стилистика (что сказывается на звучании) заметно отличается.